# difference between parameter update using tensorflow module and update using manual variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, module

I have

```
#using module
dense = tf.layers.dense(tf_dataset_l, nn_hidden, activation=tf.tanh)
logits_l = tf.layers.dense(dense, num_labels, activation=tf.nn.softmax)        
loss_l = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf_labels_l, logits=logits_l))       
optimizer_l = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss_l)

#manual
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([image_size * image_size, nn_hidden]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nn_hidden]))
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([nn_hidden, num_labels]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]))       
dense = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(tf_dataset, w1) + b1)
logits = tf.matmul(hidden, w2) + b2    
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf_labels, logits=logits))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)
```

using mnist image and in same condition, final performance of using module : 92.2% vs final performance of manual : 88.7%

I don't use some regularization trick or another. I don't know why there is difference between them. Please let me know

Comment: You have double softmax activation in the module implementation. Maybe this is the difference. There should be none in general, but clearly something is different.

Comment: The double softmax: `logits_l = tf.layers.dense(dense, num_labels, activation=tf.nn.softmax)`, then you again perform `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. This is different, and since it performs better, it is also interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

**The correct answer:**

There is a double softmax activation in the first implementation when using prepared modules. The double softmax: `logits_l = tf.layers.dense(dense, num_labels, activation=tf.nn.softmax)`, then you again perform `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. This is different, and since it performs better, it is also interesting :)

It is always a good idea to test the code and see that you result in the exact computational graph you want. Good luck!

Comment: omg. thanks but the difference between them increases to 93.8% vs 88.7% .. do you know why there is difference ??